# angular 5 webpack not including model classes

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I am working with angular 5. I created some model classes which are used to serialize json data received from server. These model classes are not instantiated within the angular 5 code. When webpack creates main.bundle.js, it does not include these classes. The code compiles correctly but and I get error at runtime.

```
Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: _this.contentTemplate.init is not a function
TypeError: _this.contentTemplate.init is not a function
```

The corresponding code that where this error is occurring is:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { ContentTemplate } from '../model/content-template.model';

@Injectable()
export class ContentTemplateService {

  contentTemplate: ContentTemplate;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  init(): Observable<ContentTemplate> {

    console.log("Loading content template...");

    if (this.contentTemplate) {
      return Observable.of(this.contentTemplate);
    } 

    return this.http.get<ContentTemplate>('/template')
           .map(
               contentTemplate => { 
                 this.contentTemplate = contentTemplate; 
                 this.contentTemplate.init();
                 return this.contentTemplate;
               },
               error => {
                 // TODO: error loading template
               }
             );
  }

}
```

The content template model class is as below:

```
import { Container } from './container.model';
import { DataDefinition } from './data-definition.model';

export class ContentTemplate {

  id: string;
  version: string;

  dataDefinition: DataDefinition;

  init() {
    this.dataDefinition.init();
  }
}
```

If I create an instance of these classes in any of the classes where there are being used by calling:

```
const myContentTemplate = new ContentTemplate();
```

then webpack includes this class.

I am new to webpack and angular so I am not able to figure out if I am missing something.

Thanks.

Comment: This has nothing to do with webpack. You're incorrectly assuming that unmarshalling JSON to objects will create instances of your class. It won't. Never. JSON.parse() doesn't know and care about your class. It creates POJOs, i.e. plain old JavaScript objects with just attributes. You're lying to yourself by telling TypeScript that your http.get() returns instances of ContentTemplate. It doesn't.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet. Is there are way to do it? I was planning to go OO route of putting operations in the model class.

Comment: There is way: you need to create instances of your class yourself, and copy all the attributes of the POJO to the class instance. You also need to do that with the inner objects (DataDefinition).